# File::Copy reports incorrect failure on NFS write?

Tags: perl, nfs

My Perl script is moving files onto an NFS mounted filesystem, using the move function from File::Copy.  Recently, some of the files returned an error, causing my script to print the message "move returned 0, A file or directory in the path name does not exist." (move returns 1 on success, 0 on error, the error message is from $!)

The really weird thing is that the system that processes the files has reported back that it successfully processed the files that failed!  I have never seen an error message from a successful write before, so I wonder if it has something to do with NFS.  I thought it was strange that in a run where 28 files were moved, the first 24 failed and the last 4 succeeded.  The script has been running with no errors for several months, and has now demonstrated this problem twice in 2 weeks.

The host is running on AIX, though I doubt that makes a difference.

Comment: Try using [File::Copy::Reliable](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Copy::Reliable) because of the added instability of working over a network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a NFS issue, not Perl. NFS could be really weird in some cases.

You should stat/read the writed file and do not depend on reported errors.

The File::Copy::Reliable module use the same error handling it will fail with same error.

Form source:

```
copy( $source, $destination )
    || croak("copy_reliable($source, $destination) failed: $!");
```

Simply put the copy into an eval block, and try to read/stat the file in the destination.

If you really cautious you could use md5/sha1 hash on both files to be sure that they are the same.

Regards,

Comment: I think you are right about it being NFS.  I looked at the code for the move function in File::Copy.  It is specifically checking for the case "Did rename return an error even though it succeeded, because $to is on a remote NFS file system, and NFS lost the server's ack?" So now I just have to figure out why the code is not returning success.

Comment: We were able to prove that no data was lost, so we are going to keep a close eye on the system.  It if happens again, I will probably end up replacing File::Copy::move with my own function with a ridiculous amount of error checking and logging.  Thanks everyone.